# I am stuck with face tracking in Blender

Tags: tracking

Not new to Blender but first time attempting to track a face. The footage is a person looking down at first and looking up, shot with a tripod. I have done everything I was advised to do, and I am constantly facing two problems:

1. The 3D Markers to mesh function is not aligned with the footage when inside the camera view
2. The face shape is clearly in the other way, not capturing the proper face structure.

[image: solve error is also low, added keyframes A and B between the face looking up]

[image: this is how the 3D mesh comes up]

The footage was shot on an Iphone 14 pro max. Hence the resolution and the frame rates were applied.